# Set choice column value for a new page using Sharepoint PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, modern-pages

I am creating pages though Sharepoint PnP PowerShell and have been able to set the Title for the page.

```
Add-PnPClientSidePage -Name "Sample Page"
Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Sample Page" -Title "Sample Page Title"
```

There is a custom Choice Field column called "Item Language" (values fr or en) defined for the Site Pages list.

How can I set the Item Language column value for a page added with `Add-PnPClientSidePage` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs some additional commandlets to be executed as we cannot yet set the value of custom columns using `Set-PnPClientSidePage` command.

For this, you need to use the internal name of the column `Item Language`.

Secondly, you need to use `Get-PnPClientSidePage` command to get the created page and then use its `Id` to set the value of your column as below:

```
Add-PnPClientSidePage -Name “Sample Page”
Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Sample Page" -Title "Sample Page Title"
$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Sample Page"
Set-PnPListItem -List "Site Pages" -Identity $page.PageListItem.Id -Values @{"ItemLanguage"="fr"}
```

Please change the value of column to that of the internal name of the column in your environment.